# How to add list of blog posts in Blog section with netlify CMS?

Tags: hugo, netlify-cms

I already asked this [question in the Netlify community](https://community.netlify.com/t/how-to-add-list-of-blog-posts-in-blog-section-with-netlify-cms/16651) but no response yet so I thought I should also post the question here in case someone could help solve the problem.

I am using Hugo-academia template for my site. It works fine but the issue is that I am unable to view a list of my posts in the [BLOG](https://gbemisola-ojediran.netlify.app/blog/) section. I have three sections(About | BLOG | Resume) on the [website](https://gbemisola-ojediran.netlify.app/) I'm working on

Once I create a post with Netlify-CMS, it creates the post successfully and I can see the post under ***Recent Posts*** in my [homepage](https://gbemisola-ojediran.netlify.app/). But if I click on [BLOG](https://gbemisola-ojediran.netlify.app/blog/), I am unable to see the accumulation of my blog posts.

Unfortunately, the Github repo is private but here's how my content directory looks like (Kindly note that I am using [hugo-academic](https://github.com/themefisher/Academia-hugo) theme)

`content/blog/index.md`

I expect that once I create a blog post (let's call it 'new-post') with netlify CMS, a folder should be created automatically and create a pull request on my GitHub. Something like this:

[image]

(On a side note, I changed `post` in the original theme to `blog` in mine so the URL will make use of blog instead of post).

Kindly help me with this problem. I can provide any other details that may assist with getting this problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with the template, I was able to solve my problem.

I was able to solve this problem by changing a little detail in netlify's cms `config.yml` located in `static/admin/`. I changed `folder: 'content/post'` to `folder: 'content/blog'`

The list of posts is now located at `../blog` but the downside is that the page looses its original soothing styling.